# how to achieve this effect on iphone，just like the ios 5.0 music app？

Tags: ios, tableview

in the ios 5.0 music app ,when long press on a tableview cell,the song detail will show upside the cell in a pop view. It is easy to do.  However ,when you drag the long press,the pop view will follow you finger to show the next cell detail,I have no idea how to do this.

[image]

Comment: post images . just wording can't understand by others

Answer (score 0):

It's a `UIMenuController`. Check the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UIMenuController_Class/UIMenuController.html).

Comment: the problem is ，if i drag the long press ，will the menu go with my finger to show the next cell detail. very sorry that i can not make a gif to show this. please use the ios 5.0 music app for detail. many thanks.

Comment: You would need to implement a custom control then!